# linux find command: exclude path from result

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I used the find command to find all python files in a folder, and exlude some folder.

`find . -type d \( -path ./venv -o -path ./virtualenv -o -path ./lib \) -prune -o -iname '*.py'`

It's give the following output:

```
...
./tests/test_a.py
./venv
```

How can I tweak the `find` command to exclude ./venv in the resultset?

Comment: What happens if you remove `-o`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify any actions, `find` will implicitly use `-print` for any file that matches your expression. `-prune` always evaluates as true (in addition to preventing further recursion), which is why `./venv` still ends up being printed.

To avoid that, simply add a `-print` to your other branch:

```
find . -type d \( -path ./venv -o -path ./virtualenv -o -path ./lib \) -prune \
       -o -iname '*.py' -print
```

Now there's an action, so `find` no longer prints everything that happens to evaluate as true, and instead only prints the files you're explicitly looking for.